# insert nan's instead of a float in cassandra using python3

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cqlsh

I want to insert nan instead of the float values using python code. Here is what I'm trying, and always end up with a typecast error:

```
example input_map <int, float> {1:0.9, 2:0.8, 3:NaN}
for key in input_map:
    if (not math.isnan(input_map[key])):
        out_values[key] = values[key]
    else:
        out_values[key] = float('nan')
```

Tried all the possible combinations in the else float(nan) | float('NaN') |float("NaN") etc

```
// Insert statement to be executed:
insert into keyspace.cfamily (var1, var2, map_data) values ('value1', 'value2', {1:0.9, 2:0.8, 3:nan})
```

cql error:
cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to make float from 'nan'"

C* version details:
cqlsh:keyspace> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.4 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

Python version:
$python3 --version
Python 3.4.3

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Quick update: numpy.nan or float('nan') responds with value nan for which cql query fails, but the same cql works fine when I manually change that to NaN

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra's `nan` syntax is `NaN`. You have to replace python's `nan` for `NaN` when mounting the query.

Comment: Edited: Cassandra's syntax is "NaN" . You have to replace python's "nan" for "NaN" when mounting the query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can edit your own answer by clicking the _Edit_ link under the post. It's fine to explain or announce edits as comments, but updates to your answer should be done as actual edits.